# pointwise convergence in relation to derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Here's a standard textbook question:

If $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ pointwise at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n,f$ are all differentiable, does $\lim f_n'(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x$ ?

The answer is 'no', even the limit may not exist at some points, and the standard counterexample is $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n}$.

---

Now my question (also inspired by [Term-by-term differentiation of a sequence of functions without uniform convergence of derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114319/term-by-term-differentiation-of-a-sequence-of-functions-without-uniform-converge)):

Assume that

$f_n(x)\to f(x)$ pointwise at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

$f_n,f$ are all differentiable at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

$f_n'(x)\to g(x)$ pointwise at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (this eliminates the standard examples like above)

Does it imply $g(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x$ ?

Probably the answer is still 'no' (and 'yes' for uniform convergence), but I couldn't find a counterexample here.

Comment: [Would this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999768/uniform-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-to-a-function-g-but-their-deriv) help?

Comment: that's it, thanks

Comment: A different answer is perhaps more informative: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4347360/if-f-n-converges-uniformly-on-an-interval-does-f-n-converge/4347406#4347406